# Using JMathPlot with Clojure, .addLinePlot method is giving error

Tags: clojure, plot

I'm using JMathPlot with Clojure as in below code:

```
(ns plot.core
 (:gen-class)
 (:import [org.math.plot Plot2DPanel])
 (:import [javax.swing JFrame]))

(let [plot (new Plot2DPanel)
      frame (JFrame. "plot")] 
  (doto plot
    (.addLegend "SOUTH")
    (.addLinePlot [1 2 3]  [22 33 44]))
  (doto frame 
    (.setContentPane plot)
    (.setSize 300 300)
    (.setVisible true)))
```

but there is an error of "No Matching method":

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: addLinePlot for class org.math.plot.Plot2DPanel
            Reflector.java:80 clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod
            Reflector.java:28 clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod
                    jmp.clj:8 plot.core/eval56
           Compiler.java:6511 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
           Compiler.java:6952 clojure.lang.Compiler.load
             NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 user/eval48
           Compiler.java:6511 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
           Compiler.java:6477 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                core.clj:2797 clojure.core/eval
                 main.clj:245 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                 main.clj:266 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                 main.clj:266 clojure.main/repl
             RestFn.java:1096 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:56 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate[fn]
                 AFn.java:159 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
                 AFn.java:151 clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo
                 core.clj:601 clojure.core/apply
                core.clj:1771 clojure.core/with-bindings*
              RestFn.java:425 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
    interruptible_eval.clj:41 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
   interruptible_eval.clj:171 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval[fn]
                core.clj:2278 clojure.core/comp[fn]
   interruptible_eval.clj:138 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next[fn]
                  AFn.java:24 clojure.lang.AFn.run
             (Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
             (Unknown Source) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
             (Unknown Source) java.lang.Thread.run
```

code is based upon an example from JMathPlot webpage, so I'm not sure how the method is not present? 
The problem is specifically in addLinePlot, as I'm running the code without this method and it's working correctly!

Comment: I used the same code with Jython and it worked perfectly. with Clojure I can show a new instance from Plot2DPanel in JFrame but can't .addLinePlot to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, .addLinePlot will not accept less than 3 arguments as per example in their site

> plot.addLinePlot("my plot", x, y);

If "my plot" is removed, method will throw an error as above!

Answer (score 3):

`addLinePlot` method requires arrays as its arguments, not vectors. You have to use plain arrays, like this:

```
(.addLinePlot plot (double-array [1 2 3]) (double-array [22 33 44]))
```

See [here](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Arrays) for more info on arrays in clojure.

Comment: thanks for the link, I never notice this part of clojure and java interop, anyway it didn't solve the problem, I'm receiving the same error.